# Can TWTweetComposeViewController be modified?

Tags: twitter

Basically can I achieve something like this http://www.pohrani.com/f/3L/WK/4bBD7bO6/sample.png

I want a camera icon which will call UIImagePickerController for a user to select which picture to attach to tweet. Can this be done or once a TWTweetComposeViewController is called I can't add images to tweet?

Answer (score 1):

Use [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController) instead. Fully customizable.